# Modifying Laravel 4 resource controller routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'd like to modify some of the automatically generated Laravel routes and I'm not certain if this is in fact possible or not.

I have a model called `Workspace` (using Eloquent) and I created a resource controller using artisan.

```
php artisan controller:make WorkspaceController
```

And I also added the routes using this command in my `routes.php` file.

```
Route::resource('workspace', 'PROJECT\Controllers\Workspaces\WorkspaceController');
```

Since I want to use getIndex to list the available resources I'd like the index route to be `workspaces` and not `workspace`, whereas I'd like to keep the structure for other scenarios like `workspace/{id}/edit` and so on.

Do you know how I can modify the default routes that `Route::resource` creates?

Comment: This isn't so much changing how a Resource controllers work as messing with routes in general - You're effectively wanting to resource 'workspaces' and 'workspace' to the same "thing". You can use The Shift Exchange's answer to do so (to route to the same controller). Otherwise you can [extend the router](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php) and replace Laravel's with your extended version if you want.

Comment: I guess the real question is: Do you have a good business reason for doing so? Anything stopping you from routing `/workspaces` to `WorkspaceController@index` ?

Comment: Thanks, I decided it was best to define all the routes myself since I have much better control of them that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "modify" the resource() route as such.

You can either add more routes on top of the resource(), or just define each of the routes individually, and therefore have full control over your routes.

[Read this blog about routes - it will shed some light on the issue](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil)

An example to add more routes you could do something like:

```
 Route::get('extra', 'PROJECT\Controllers\Workspaces\WorkspaceController');
 Route::resource('workspace', 'PROJECT\Controllers\Workspaces\WorkspaceController');
```

Note the extra routes are best defined BEFORE the resource() route

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. It's a shame you can't define the individual routes and still use resource().